# Deserializing JSON search results into strongly typed lists (JSON.NET)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have search results in JSON and I want to deserialize it into strongly typed objects

For example:

```
{
    searchresult: {
        resultscount: 15,
        results: [
            {
                resultnumber: 1,
                values: [
                    {
                        key:    "bookid",
                        value:  1424
                    },
                    {
                        key:    "name",
                        value:  "C# in depth"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I have this POCO

```
public class Book {
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get a list of books. Yes, I can write my own custom deserializer for this case, but I want to use a default deserializer.

Is it possible to do something like that?

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Book>>(json);
```

Comment: You're 90% there.. Just create a few intermediate classes that contain the search result data.

Comment: Post your classes into http://json2csharp.com/ and adapt as needed.

Comment: Yes, but I will get something like List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, but I want to get List<Book>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.NET will not do this without any customization.  You have the following approaches:

1. Post your classes to http://json2csharp.com/ to create a literal representation of your JSON, then use Linq to transform the result into a list of `Book` classes:

   ```
   public class Value
   {
       public string key { get; set; }
       public string value { get; set; } // Type changed from "object" to "string".
   }

   public class Result
   {
       public int resultnumber { get; set; }
       public List<Value> values { get; set; }
   }

   public class Searchresult
   {
       public int resultscount { get; set; }
       public List<Result> results { get; set; }
   }

   public class RootObject
   {
       public Searchresult searchresult { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And then

   ```
       var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
       var books = root.searchresult.results.Select(result => new Book { Name = result.values.Find(v => v.key == "name").value, BookId = result.values.Find(v => v.key == "bookid").value });
   ```
2. Create a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to convert the JSON to your POCO as it is being read, for instance:

   ```
   internal class BookConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanWrite
       {
           get
           {
               return false;
           }
       }

       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(Book);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var values = serializer.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(reader);
           if (values == null)
               return existingValue;
           var book = existingValue as Book;
           if (book == null)
               book = new Book();
           // The following throws an exception on missing keys.  You could handle this differently if you prefer.
           book.BookId = values.Find(v => v.Key == "bookid").Value;
           book.Name = values.Find(v => v.Key == "name").Value;
           return book;
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }

   public class Result
   {
       public int resultnumber { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("values")] 
       [JsonConverter(typeof(BookConverter))]
       public Book Book { get; set; }
   }

   public class Searchresult
   {
       public int resultscount { get; set; }
       public List<Result> results { get; set; }
   }

   public class RootObject
   {
       public Searchresult searchresult { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   and then

   ```
       var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
       var books = root.searchresult.results.Select(result => result.Book);
   ```

   Here I only implemented `ReadJson` as your question only asks about deserialization .  You could implement `WriteJson` similarly if required.
3. Use [`Linq to JSON`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to load the JSON into a structured hierarchy of [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)'s then convert the result to `Book`'s with Linq:

   ```
       var books = 
           JObject.Parse(json).Descendants()
               .OfType<JProperty>()
               .Where(p => p.Name == "values")
               .Select(p => p.Value.ToObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>())
               .Select(values => new Book { Name = values.Find(v => v.Key == "name").Value, BookId = values.Find(v => v.Key == "bookid").Value })
               .ToList();
   ```

Comment: @ravenger - added one more option.